# Would poisson's ratio also result in stresses in lateral directions?

Tags: solid-mechanics

This is kind of like a basic question which students might ask in their bachelor's level of education, which I want to refresh my knowledge about. So if I apply a load in a single longitudinal direction, say $X$ direction onto a material having a poisson's ratio of say 0.3, I know that it will also result in strains along the other lateral directions i.e. $Y$ and $Z$. But will it also create stresses in those directions i.e. $\sigma_Y$ and $\sigma_Z$? (assume no longitudinal force is applied in the $Y$ and $Z$ directions).

Comment: Stresses are related to forces.  All internal forces in the material must balance the external forces.  Therefore, for homogeneous deformations, there cannot be unbalanced stresses in Y and Z.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee, then it means either there are forces or there aren't any in the directions of Y and Z. Since I am not applying any contraint in the Y and Z directions, this makes me believe that I don't have any resistance to deformation in Y and Z directions. Hence there are no forces at all in these directions. Which basically implies that there are no stresses in these directions.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

It should be obvious that your examples will have stress components in the X and Y directions (assuming the structure is in the XY plane and the thickness is in the Z direction.)

Think about the boundary conditions around the curved edge. The stress component *normal to the boundary* must equal the external force normal to the boundary, which is zero.

So unless you think *all* the stress components at the curved boundary are zero (which doesn't make any sense - if it was true, cutting a hole in a plate would not cause a stress concentration around the hole but a *reduction* in stress around the hole!) there must be direct stress components in both X and Y, and also shear stress in the XY plane.

The previous two paragraphs have nothing to do with Poisson's ratio.

If Poisson's ratio is non-zero and there is a *non-uniform* stress field in the XY plane, there will be also a non-uniform strain field in the XY plane. Therefore (from Poisson's ratio) there will be non-uniform strains in the Z direction.

Therefore *the top and bottom surfaces of the plate are no longer flat* because the thickness is not uniform. The same argument as before shows there must be a stress component in the Z direction.

For a "thin" plate the stresses in the Z direction are small and can usually be ignored in practice, but if you make a detailed 3D model you will find they are not exactly zero.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is not an easy way to answer this. The short way to answer is that if there is strain there is stress (and vice versa). However there are a few exceptions.

The most prominent example are thermally induced strains (that is something that I intended to write in the initial answer but I missed out). Thermally induced strains in an unconstrained object would not necessarily induce stresses (or so I understand and I would be happy to hear counterarguments).

Another example, I can think of, is that in continuum mechanics you can assume that a thin plate with forces acting parallel to the direction is in plane stress. e.g.

[image]

**Figure 1: examples of plain stress (source: [Haad](https://slidetodoc.com/formulation-of-twodimensional-elasticity-problems-professor-m-h/))**

However, what that really means is that the out of plane stress are **negligible** compared to the in plane stresses.

So, the way I interpret it, is that stresses develop in all direction when there is a strain involved, however, the exact magnitude is a matter of boundary constraints and loading.

Comment: can you check out the comment I made under my post? When I replied to Biswajit Banerjee.

Answer (score 1):

Not if the loading in the x-direction is uniform and causes uniform compression deformation in the x-direction.

It will just cause strain in the y and z-direction.

But if there is any constrain on the part not allowing it to expand laterally then there will be lateral stresses.

Here is a [Link to article.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Poisson%27s_ratio) in Wikiwand on the subject.

.

[image: Poisons deformation]